# updating ans ios app is causing issues whereas reinstall works fine

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, app-store

i am experiencing a weird problem. last week i submitted updated app into App store and when it comes live i updated already installed app on my iPhone. i saw lots of issues on my home controller table view. after that i deleted and reinstall the app and it worked fine.

i found same behavior on some other test devices too. 
i find it as a big issue because end user will never do reinstallation, he will always update the all and find these issues.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share more details on what kind of task are you doing on your home controller table view? Are you using some pre-populated databases etc. ?

Comment: Are you using Core Data? If so and you've made changes to your data model then this may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be caused by incompatible models between those two versions. For example if you are caching your model objects it would be good practice to clear cache upon upgrade to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your application crashed due to update in core data model. Solution for this is you need to learn data migration of coredata. you can learn form [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html).

Hope you will get what i mean.

Comment: also visit this link too it's give step by step solution : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/core-data_schema-versioning-and-lightweight-migrations/

Comment: i am not using core data or sqlite in my app. it is simple xib file which is having a carousel and a table view. now these linking of table rows as per their row select delegate is mismatching